# How to install and Run Visual Basic 6.0 Application on Windows 7 64 bit Operating System

Tags: windows, windows-7, vb6, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have checked several forums and stackoverflow, I am not get any feasible solution regarding "How to install and Run Visual Basic 6.0 Application on Windows 7?", some of the thread says VB6 is a 16 bit module, will work on Windows 7 32 bit only not on 64 bit. How to make VB apps(6.0) to work on Windows 7 64 bit, is it possible., If it is possible, how to make work. Your input might help for me.

Comment: How do you "run Visual Basic 6.0 application on Windows", say, XP? It's same with 7.

Comment: VB6 compiles to 32-bit code.  If there is any 16-bit code involved it would be a setup bootstrapper if you are using some very old application packaging tool.  People install and run VB6 programs all the time on 64-bit Windows all the way up to Windows 8.x systems.